# import _winapi ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winapi'

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, ubuntu

I want to use NULL in python as implemented in java. I came across `asyncio.windows_event` which contains the `NULL` class and it works fine on windows. However, when I tried to run the same code in Ubuntu, I got the following error:

```
import _winapi
       ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_winapi'
```

I understand this supports only windows platform. Please can someone help me with Ubuntu's equivalent where I can import NULL just as its possible for windows. In windows, you can import NULL as:

```
from asyncio.window_event import NULL
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice to see the context of the problem. Why you need to use winapi NULL?
Maybe you can easly solve this with standard pythons `None`?

Comment: python's None at a point produces a Nonetype error, which means I may have to walk through many codes to catch all the None objects I wanted to avoid by simply getting the python equivalent NULL . The winapi NULL only works in windows, I want the ubuntu winapi NULL equivalent

Answer (score 0):

Upon surfing the internet, I came across the python `null` package. I installed it by

```
pip install null
```

and import it as

```
from null import Null
```

and it worked just fine.

There is another one called `nulltype`. One may install it with

```
pip install nulltype
```

and import it with

```
from nulltype import NullType
```

Although I haven't used it to test how it works I have only tried `Null`